# Authbind giving "Operation not Permitted" when running a flask server

Tags: 22.04, python, flask

I am trying to use authbind for my flask server as I need the server to run on port 443 for the ssl certificate. So far I have looked online and used

```
sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/443;
sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/443;
sudo chown ig13 /etc/authbind/byport/443;
```

and then I would use

```
authbind --deep python3 main.py
```

However this is when I get the "Operation not Permitted" error.
I have attached a screenshot of the server:

[image: logs]

Edit:
I am able to run the same flask server using port 443 as windows doesn't treat it as privileged. I have the server running on port 1024 on linux at the moment, but I would prefer for it to run on port 443 whilst being on linux.

Comment: Does some other process have port 443 allocated? Do  `sudo lsof -itcp:443`. Read `man lsof systemd-dnsmasq`.

Comment: @waltinator I get `COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
python3 1286 ig13   12u  IPv4  36968      0t0  TCP server:50230->162.159.134.234:https (ESTABLISHED)` when running that command.

Comment: After running `sudo reboot now` I get `canonical 789 root   10u  IPv4  29921      0t0  TCP server:60086->commercial-systems-content-cache-2.ps5.canonical.com:https (ESTABLISHED)`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Turns out I just had to restart twice and it started working.